# como faço para inserir todas as linhas retornadas no banco via serialize no ajax

Tags: php, ajax

estou fazendo uma pagina inicial.php que trás informação de eu uma segunda página function.php via ajax até ai tudo normal porém nesse retorno trás uma tabela com as informações do banco e um botão para cadastrar, nesse botão chamo a função cadastrar que se encontra na primeira pagina inicial.php que envia o formulario via serialize para a pagina cade.php para inserir em uma outra tabela no banco porém só consigo inserir a ultima linha, eu teria que fazer um loop como que eu faria segue os códigos abaixo:

inicial.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        var teste = $("#teste").val();
        alert(teste);
        $.ajax({
            url: "function.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                teste:teste
            },
            success: function(result){
            alert(result);
            $("#div1").html(result);
        }});
    });
});
</script>
<script>
    function cade(){
        var form = $("#form").serialize();
        var action = "cade";
        alert(form+' / '+action);

         $.ajax({
            url: "cade.php",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            data: form,
            success: function(result){
            alert(result);
        }});
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>

<input type="text" id="teste" name="teste" value="" />
<button>Get External Content</button>
<br><br>

<div id="div1"><h2>Let jQuery AJAX Change This Text</h2></div>
</body>
</html>
```

function.php:

```
<?php 
$con = @mysqli_connect("localhost",'root','','test')or die("erro no banco");


$teste = @$_POST['teste'];
$select = @mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM test.teste where serial = '$teste' ") or die ("erro na query 2");

    echo "<form id='form' name='form' method='post' action='' >";
    echo "<table border='1'>";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<th>SERIAL</th>";
    echo "<th>EQUIPAMENTO</th>";
    echo "<th>FOTO</th>";
    echo "</tr>";
while($result = mysqli_fetch_array($select)){
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td><input type='text' value='".$result['serial']."' id='serial'  name='serial'/></td>";
    echo "<td><input type='text' value='".$result['equipamento']."' id='eq' name='eq' /></td>";
    echo "<td><input type='text' value='".$result['foto']."' id='foto' name='foto' /></td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
    echo "</table>";
?>
<input type="button" value="Cadastrar" onclick="cade();" />
</form>
```

cade.php:

```
<?php 
    $con = @mysqli_connect("localhost",'root','','test')or die("erro no banco");
    $serial = $_REQUEST['serial'];
    $eq = $_REQUEST['eq'];
    $foto = $_REQUEST['foto'];

    print_r(@$_POST);
    $inseri = @mysqli_query($con,"insert into test.nova (serial,equipamento,foto) values ('$serial','$eq','$foto') ") or die ("erro na query");

    //echo "<script>window.history.back();</script>";    
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Você precisa enviar os campos do formulário como arrays. Para isso, inclua os colchetes `[]` nos `name`s:

```
name='serial[]'
name='eq[]'
name='foto[]'
```

Ficando assim:

```
echo "<td><input type='text' value='serial$result' id='serial'  name='serial[]'/></td>";
echo "<td><input type='text' value='equip$result' id='eq' name='eq[]' /></td>";
echo "<td><input type='text' value='foto$result' id='foto' name='foto[]' /></td>";
```

No PHP, você pode fazer um `foreach` na linha do INSERT para pegar cada valor pelo índice, e incluir `[$i]` nos valores a serem inseridos no banco. Como todas as arrays possuem o mesmo tamanho, peguei a array `$serial` para fazer o `foreach` e pegar os índices em `$i`:

```
foreach($serial as $i => $valor){
    $inseri = @mysqli_query($con,"insert into test.nova (serial,equipamento,foto) values ('$serial[$i]','$eq[$i]','$foto[$i]') ") or die ("erro na query");
}
```

Comment: Valeu irmão sua sujestão deu certo muito obrigado

Comment: De nada. Vi que vc é novo no site. Você deve marcar ✓ na resposta que achou mais correta.

Comment: O ✓ fica do lado esquerdo da resposta, abaixo das setas de votação. Mais informações é importante dar uma olhada na página de [Tour](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour)... Abs!